# Canon iP3600 under Scientific Linux

Tags: printing, scientific-linux

I bought a new printer (I googled before and it looked like it's working under my OS..)

I plugged the printer in a win7 machine, installed a few hundred MBytes of  software, and it worked.

Then I plugged it in my Scientific Linux 6.1 (64bit) notebook. A printer configuration window opened, I could add the printer, great!

But: If I want to print from this notebook the status of a job is "finished", so it looks like it prints ok, but from the real world side, the printer does nothing.

I don't know what to do. Canon's website provides rpm's for Linux, but it's for i386.

What can I do?

Some info:

When I plug in the printer:

```
Apr 11 21:16:48 a kernel: usb 2-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 45
Apr 11 21:16:48 a kernel: usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=04a9, idProduct=10ca
Apr 11 21:16:48 a kernel: usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 11 21:16:48 a kernel: usb 2-6: Product: iP3600 series
Apr 11 21:16:48 a kernel: usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Canon
Apr 11 21:16:48 a kernel: usb 2-6: SerialNumber: 1754F5
Apr 11 21:16:48 a kernel: usb 2-6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Apr 11 21:16:48 a kernel: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 45 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04A9 pid 0x10CA
Apr 11 21:16:48 a udev-configure-printer: invalid or missing IEEE 1284 Device ID
Apr 11 21:16:49 a kernel: type=1400 audit(1334171809.432:164): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=22860 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
Apr 11 21:16:49 a kernel: type=1400 audit(1334171809.434:165): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=22860 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
Apr 11 21:16:49 a kernel: type=1400 audit(1334171809.434:166): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=22860 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
Apr 11 21:16:49 a kernel: type=1400 audit(1334171809.472:167): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=22860 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
Apr 11 21:16:49 a kernel: type=1400 audit(1334171809.473:168): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=22860 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
Apr 11 21:16:49 a kernel: type=1400 audit(1334171809.473:169): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=22860 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
Apr 11 21:16:49 a kernel: type=1400 audit(1334171809.473:170): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=22860 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
Apr 11 21:16:49 a udev-configure-printer: Re-enabled printer ipp://localhost:631/printers/Canon-iP3600-series
```

Comment: Have you had a look into the RPM (or un'`tar`'ed the `.deb` version they provide)?  Maybe it's really architecture-independent and you can make use of it somehow... (just kind of a wild guess, sorry)

Comment: ty for the trick, I tried it, and it looks like it doesn't work :\

Comment: Try disabling SELinux and see if it works.

Comment: What is "net-pf-10" on your system? `grep -w "net-pf-10" /etc/modprobe.conf`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8GyWg5NS

Comment: there is no modprobe.conf :(

Comment: disabling SELinux didn't helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works under:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Scientific
Description:    Scientific Linux release 6.1 (Carbon)
Release:    6.1
Codename:   Carbon
```

**Printer: Canon PIXMA iP3600**

```
lsusb: Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04a9:10ca Canon, Inc.
```

HOW TO INSTALL 

1)

```
# download RPM (select Linux/English)
http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/InkJet/PIXMA_iP_series/iP3600.aspx?type=download&page=1
```

2)

```
# with normal user
mkdir ip3600 && mv iP3600_RPM_printer.tar ip3600/ && cd ip3600 && tar -xf iP3600_RPM_printer.tar
```

3)

```
# with root in same directory
yum install -y cups-devel.i686 popt-devel.i686 && rpm -i cnijfilter-common-*.i386.rpm
yum install -y gtk2.i686 atk-devel.i686 && rpm -i cnijfilter-ip3600series-*.i386.rpm
cd .. && rm -fr ip3600
```

4)

```
# add the printer
env LC_MESSAGES=EN system-config-printer
```

Answer (score 1):

SELinux is denying udev an action, loading a kernel module, when it is trying to create the device.

A quick and easy, but non-permanent, fix is to put SELinux in Permissive Mode. As root, or using sudo, the command is

`setenforce Permissive`

Now plug in the printer and send a print job.

If that worked, then you can either

- Turn off SELinux permanently (set `SELINUX=disabled` in /etc/selinux/config)
- Leave SELinux in Permissive Mode permanently (set `SELINUX=permissive` in /etc/selinux/config)
- Correct SELinux by defining the correct context (more difficult, start here: [RHEL 6 SELinux User Guide](http://goo.gl/b6FTS))

Comment: SELinux didn't helped :)

Comment: Nice find on the answer.